# Varyings with the same name but different type, or statically used varyings in fragment shader are not declared in vertex shader: fogDepth

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader

I'm not very good at shaders. I need the fog to reflect in the water. I use Three.js sky_sun_shader. I have added the following to the fragment Shader:

*THREE.ShaderChunk[ "fog_pars_fragment" ],*

*THREE.ShaderChunk ["fog_fragment" ],*

In r71, this works fine. In r101, when I use chunk I get an error:

***THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error: 0 35715 false gl.getProgramInfoLog Variations with the same name but different type, or statically used variations in fragment shader are not declared in vertex shader: fogDepth***

How can I fix this?

The shader's code:

```
THREE.ShaderLib['water'] = {
uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.merge( [
    THREE.UniformsLib[ "fog" ], {   
            "normalSampler":    { type: "t", value: null },
            "mirrorSampler":    { type: "t", value: null },
            "alpha":            { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
            "time":             { type: "f", value: 0.0 },
            "size":         { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
            "kalbedo":      { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
            "distortionScale":  { type: "f", value: 20.0 },
            "textureMatrix" :   { type: "m4", value: new THREE.Matrix4() },
            "sunColor":         { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0x7F7F7F ) },
            "sunDirection":     { type: "v3", value: new THREE.Vector3( 0.70707, 0.70707, 0 ) },
            "eye":              { type: "v3", value: new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ) },
            "waterColor":       { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0x555555 ) }
    }
] ),
vertexShader: [
    'uniform mat4 textureMatrix;',
    'uniform float time;',
    'varying vec4 mirrorCoord;',
    'varying vec3 worldPosition;',
    'void main()',
    '{',
    '   mirrorCoord = modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );',
    '   worldPosition = mirrorCoord.xyz;',
    '   mirrorCoord = textureMatrix * mirrorCoord;',
    '   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );',
    '}'
].join('\n'),

fragmentShader: [
    'precision highp float;',
    'uniform sampler2D mirrorSampler;',
    'uniform float alpha;',
    'uniform float time;',
        'uniform float size;',
        'uniform float kalbedo;',
    'uniform float distortionScale;',
    'uniform sampler2D normalSampler;',
    'uniform vec3 sunColor;',
    'uniform vec3 sunDirection;',
    'uniform vec3 eye;',
    'uniform vec3 waterColor;',
    'varying vec4 mirrorCoord;',
    'varying vec3 worldPosition;',
    'vec4 getNoise( vec2 uv )',
    '{',
    '   vec2 uv0 = ( uv / 103.0 ) + vec2(time / 17.0, time / 29.0);',
    '   vec2 uv1 = uv / 107.0-vec2( time / -19.0, time / 31.0 );',
    '   vec2 uv2 = uv / vec2( 8907.0, 9803.0 ) + vec2( time / 101.0, time / 97.0 );',
    '   vec2 uv3 = uv / vec2( 1091.0, 1027.0 ) - vec2( time / 109.0, time / -113.0 );',
    '   vec4 noise = ( texture2D( normalSampler, uv0 ) ) +',
    '       ( texture2D( normalSampler, uv1 ) ) +',
    '       ( texture2D( normalSampler, uv2 ) ) +',
    '       ( texture2D( normalSampler, uv3 ) );',
    '   return noise * 0.5 - 1.0;',
    '}',

    'void sunLight( const vec3 surfaceNormal, const vec3 eyeDirection, float shiny, float spec, float diffuse, inout vec3 diffuseColor, inout vec3 specularColor )',
    '{',
    '   vec3 reflection = normalize( reflect( -sunDirection, surfaceNormal ) );',
    '   float direction = max( 0.0, dot( eyeDirection, reflection ) );',
    '   specularColor += pow( direction, shiny ) * sunColor * spec;',
    '   diffuseColor += max( dot( sunDirection, surfaceNormal ), 0.0 ) * sunColor * diffuse;',
    '}',
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "common" ],
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "fog_pars_fragment" ],
    'void main()',
    '{',
    '   vec4 noise = getNoise( worldPosition.xz * size  );',
    '   vec3 surfaceNormal = normalize( noise.xzy * vec3( 1.5, 1.0, 1.5 ) );',
    '   vec3 diffuseLight = vec3(0.0);',
    '   vec3 specularLight = vec3(0.0);',
    '   vec3 worldToEye = eye-worldPosition;',
    '   vec3 eyeDirection = normalize( worldToEye );',
    '   sunLight( surfaceNormal, eyeDirection, 100.0, 2.0, 0.5, diffuseLight, specularLight );',
    '   float distance = length(worldToEye);',
    '   vec2 distortion = surfaceNormal.xz * ( 0.001 + 1.0 / distance ) * distortionScale;',
    '   vec3 reflectionSample = vec3( texture2D( mirrorSampler, mirrorCoord.xy / mirrorCoord.z + distortion ) );',
    '   float theta = max( dot( eyeDirection, surfaceNormal ), 0.0 );',
    '   float rf0 = 0.3;',
    '   float reflectance = rf0 + ( 1.0 - rf0 ) * pow( ( 1.0 - theta ), 5.0 );',
    '   vec3 scatter = max( 0.0, dot( surfaceNormal, eyeDirection ) ) * waterColor;',
    '   vec3 albedo = mix( sunColor * diffuseLight * 0.3 + scatter, ( vec3( 0.1 ) + reflectionSample * 0.9 + reflectionSample * specularLight ), reflectance ) ;',
    '   vec3 outgoingLight = albedo *kalbedo;',
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "fog_fragment" ],
    '   gl_FragColor = vec4( outgoingLight, alpha );',
    '}'
].join('\n')
```

};

[image: fog reflection]

Answer (score 2):

You need to pay attention to varying declaration that should be consistent across vertex and fragment shaders when embedding code from ShaderChunks.

In your case, you used code from the 2 fragment shaders fog_pars_fragment and fog_fragment

Thus you need to also add the chuncks of the matching vertex shaders fog_pars_vertex and fog_vertex (into your vertex shader). fog_pars_vertex is declaring the missing varying

```
// fog_pars_vertex.glsl

#ifdef USE_FOG

    varying float fogDepth;

#endif
```

```
// fog_vertex.glsl

#ifdef USE_FOG

    fogDepth = -mvPosition.z;

#endif
```

Comment: Thanks. I also added chunks of vertex shader. Now it doesn't throw an error. But still there is no reflection of the fog.